# how to use variable in parameter name

Tags: powershell, arguments

I am trying to read multiple files in powershell script in a for-loop always switching the file name dynamically.

I tried a different notation, but I'm still getting errors.
The code is like:

```
$fileName1 = "D:\file333"   
$fileName2 = "D:\file444"
$datePattern =" C.{3} "
[Char[]]$buffer = new-object char[] 10000
for ($j=1; $j -le 2; $j++) 
{
    [string]$fileNumber = $j.ToString()
    $inFile = new-object -TypeName System.IO.StreamReader -ArgumentList 
    $fileName($fileNumber)
    [int]$bytesRead = $inFile.Read($buffer, 0, $buffer.Length)

    while ($bytesRead -gt 0) {
        [string]$bufferString = -join $buffer
        $results = $bufferString | Select-String $datePattern -AllMatches
        $results.Matches.Value
        [int]$bytesRead = $inFile.Read($buffer, 0, $buffer.Length)
    }    
}
```

I have two questions:

1. What would be a right notation for the `-ArgumentList`, to get `FileName1` and then `FileName2`?
2. Does the `Read` method applied on the `inFile` really requires a `Char[]` type as argument for `$buffer`? And Is it possible to get the `[String]` parameter instead?

Can someone give me a hint?

Comment: Please [format your code and sample input/output properly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/248777).

Answer (score 0):

Okay,

I'm sure you were reminded when you first submitted the question, but **please** remember to put your code in a code block, like so:

```
$fileName1 = "D:\file333"

$fileName2 = "D:\file444"

$datePattern =" C.{3} "

[Char[]]$buffer = new-object char[] 10000

for ($j=1; $j -le 2; $j++)

{

   [string]$fileNumber = $j.ToString()

   $inFile = new-object -TypeName System.IO.StreamReader -ArgumentList

   $fileName($fileNumber)

   [int]$bytesRead = $inFile.Read($buffer, 0, $buffer.Length)

   while ($bytesRead -gt 0) 
   {

      [string]$bufferString = -join $buffer

      $results = $bufferString | Select-String $datePattern -AllMatches

      $results.Matches.Value

      [int]$bytesRead = $inFile.Read($buffer, 0, $buffer.Length) 
    }

}
```

Now, I'm REALLY unsure of what you're trying to do here. Whatever it is, I strongly suggest you create a well founded question here around it.

In any case, powershell doesn't support the behavior you're trying to create. It's an easy newbie trap to fall into. Oh, I want to find files 1 and 2, so I make a loop and use the iterator, *right?* **Wrong!**

You need to loop over a collection containing the files. Powershell doesn't think of the files as part of a collection unless you *put it in one*.

Try this.

```
$files = @("D:\file3333", "D:\file444")
$datePattern =" C.{3} "
[Char[]]$buffer = new-object char[] 10000

foreach(file in files)
{
   [int]$bytesRead = new-object -TypeName System.IO.StreamReader -ArgumentList $file | $_.Read($buffer, 0, $buffer.length)
   while($bytesRead -gt 0)
   {
      [string]$bufferString = -join $buffer

      $results = $bufferString | Select-String $datePattern -AllMatches

      $results.Matches.Value

      [int]$bytesRead = $inFile.Read($buffer, 0, $buffer.Length) 
    }

}
```

Here, we put the files into a collection, and iterate over that collection with a foreach loop. We can collapse your multiple lines to call the file into a buffer stream into one line by using the pipe operator.

I have NO IDEA what you're trying to do in the while loop, so I'd be happy to help you make it a bit more powershell friendly, but you'll have to ask the question you mean to ask before I can do so.

Comment: Thank you Philippe, it helps me to eliminate one more newbee obstacle! I read a huge file part by part and in the while loop looking for patterns